# Sequelize op.like не работает корректно

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Я недавно столкнулся с работой базы данных в node.

Теперь у меня проблема с запросом `Sequelize`.

Есть простой код. И там `op.like` выдает не корректный запрос `sql`.

В место `%delay%` в запросе появляетса `'\"%delay%\"'`.

Вот часть кода и ответ от сервера.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const shortcodes = await Shortcode.findAll({
      where: {
           project_id: project.id,
             settings: {
                 [Op.like]: `%delay%`
             }
           }
      });
```

Вот сам `Sql` созданный данной библиотекой.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `shortcodes` AS `shortcode`
WHERE `shortcode`.`project_id` = 1
  AND `shortcode`.`settings` LIKE '\"%delay%\"';
```

Comment: Ну ежли смотреть справку, то там в примере используются прямые кавычки, а не обратные. `[Op.like]: '%delay%'`

Comment: @Akina Я все типы ковычек пробывал, результат тот же.

Comment: какого типа колонка settings?

Comment: @nörbörnën `settings -> text`. Текстовой тип в `mysql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прорыв весь интернет наткнулся на профиль `github` одного человека. У которого была примерно идентичная проблема.

И как я понял это ошибка самой библиотеки `Sequelize`.

Вот решение данной проблемы.

Может и вам пригодиться.

Уже измененный и рабочий код:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const shortcodes = await Shortcode.findAll({
      where: {
           project_id: project.id,
             settings: {
                 [Op.like]: Sequelize.literal('\'%delay%\'')
             }
           }
      });
```

Вот уже корректный сгенерированный ՝sql՝ запрос.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `shortcodes` AS `shortcode`
WHERE `shortcode`.`project_id` = 1
  AND `shortcode`.`settings` LIKE '%delay%';
```

А вот сам [ресурс](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12073) откуда все это я прочитал.